# Get one of group elements using index failed

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to get one of elements with XPath in selenium WebdriverIO.

I have a group of  `<input>` elements which as children of an element  `<div id="content">` the first of it's group(sorry about the dev's legacy product, but I am trying to play the QA part)

All `<input>` element are placed like this

```
/html/body/div[9]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]/input
/html/body/div[9]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/input
/html/body/div[9]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[6]/span[1]/input
/html/body/div[9]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/span[1]/input
/html/body/div[9]/div/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[8]/span[1]/input
```

And when I tried to get one of it in for loop

```
var i, tar;
for (i = 1; (tar = '//div[@id="content"][1]//input['+i+']') && browser.isExisting(tar); i++) {
}
```

Always get all of them instead one only(checked by Firefinder)

Can't this be done by using index?

Comment: I'd try this one, with parenthesis: `'(//div[@id="content"][1]//input)['+i+']'`

Comment: Do you want to get the first of it's group using index?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following xpath `(//div[@id="content"][1]//input)[1]`. 
You can change the index to get the specific element.